# Как склонять название курсов в кавычках?

Tags: склонение, кавычки, названия

Можно ли склонять названия курсов в кавычках?

*Курсы "Логистики", курсы "Английского языка".*

Answer (score 1):

А заведомо не надо кавычить названия курсов, тогда не возникнет необходимость их склонять.

*Курсы логистики, курсы английского языка.*

Но вот закавыченный курс - «Ламинирование и ботокс ресниц». А это потому что он в именительном падеже. Без слова "курс" будет склоняться:

*На «Ламинировании и ботоксе ресниц» мы наконец узнали, что такое счастье.*